# What does "Crossbone Crunch" mean?

Tags: movie, dont-look-up

In Scifi-comedy movie *Don't Look Up* (2021), Kate discovers a moving comet in her observation, and
her team celebrates the discovery:

> Kate: This is nuts! This is so crazy!
>
> Woman: I've got a hard cider and a bag of **Crossbone Crunch**.

What does "Crossbone Crunch" mean?

Comment: Sounds like it's intended to be a snack food

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Crossbone Crunch" appears to be a fictional brand of snack chips of some description. An [earlier version of the script](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/dont-look-up-2021.pdf) also has him finding a fictional brand of soft drink, "*Diet Sparkles*"

> **RANDALL**: *Comet Dibiasky. It definitely has a ring to it.*
>
> **WIN**: *I found four beers and three Diet Sparkles in the back fridge! It’s a party!*
>
> **NISHA**: *I’ve got a hard cider and a bag of Crossbone Crunch!*

Screenwriters often include fake brands in their scripts [in order to avoid accidental product placement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder_name#:%7E:text=Fictional%20brands%20such%20as%20Morley,than%20the%20one%20being%20advertised.) or as a placeholder for a product placement that can be [added in ADR after the film has been shot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubbing#:%7E:text=add%20or%20remove%20a%20product%20placement).

---

It might interest you to learn that in some other markets the line was dubbed differently and [localised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_localisation).

- In Norwegian it was...

> Jeg har med eplecider og en pose med baconsvor ("I have apple cider and a [bag of bacon bits](https://meny.no/varer/snacks-godteri/snacks/baconsnacks/baconsvor-7035620037696)")
>
> <sub><sup>Baconsvor is '*pork flesh slices that are fried in oil and then salted*'. In the UK we call them [pork scratchings](https://web.archive.org/web/20121209035852/http://freshersfoods.com/history-of-pork-scratchings/).</sup></sub>

- In Dutch it was

> Ik heb cider en een zak zoutjes ("I have cider and a [bag of pretzels](https://www.plus.nl/product/chio-partymix-zak-250-gram-802024)")

- In German it was

> Ich hab Cider und eine Tüte Chips ("I have cider and a [bag of potato chips](https://www.funny-frisch.de/produkte/chipsfrisch/chipsfrisch-ungarisch.html)")